# Min pool size on sql connect string

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to add a min pool size on my connection string but I am not sure how exactly to test if it works as expected. For example if I add a value of let's say 5 there are always more connections for the user I have on the connection string when I use some queries like sp_who or others I found online.

Any recommendations how to check it?

Thanks!

Edit 1:
If I have a value of 7 and kill all processes for the specific user there are always 6 active. Is there any specific reason why it's always my value minus one connection active? (based on multiple tests)

Comment: Pretty sure .NET maintains this internally.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the SQL _language_.)

Comment: @jarlh Hi, I am using SQL Server

Comment: _"I am using SQL Server"_ - then you don't need to worry about explicitly-specifying connection pooling.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling